# Now How Implement Android Push Notification?

Tags: android

I have need to implement push Notification in my app.For that when i open google side
   this messege is shown there :-

```
Important:
```

C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

please any one suggest me How I can achieve push Notification in my app.thanx in advance.

Comment: check out this tutorial http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-steps-to-run-gcm-demo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html with examples, nothing more to add

Comment: The problem with Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is that it only works for projects targeted at 3.0 or later. I'm trying to get past this problem myself.

Comment: @edwoollard your statement is wrong, GCM requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher, if you need to support lower versions you'll have to implement data pulling approach. Check server for data every x sec/mins.